# Certificate not valid yet

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

I just create Certificate in my IOS developer account.

1)generate CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest using Keychain

2)create production certificate using above certificate

3)download AppleWWDRCA.cer and ios_distribution.cer certificate

4) install both certificate

But its shows error **This certificate is not yet valid**. **[image]**

Please help me, I have check my local machine time,its correct showing today time.

Comment: double-click on the certificate and look at the "Not valid before" date. Pay attention to the time zone and verify the time zone on your mac is set similarly and that the "not valid before" date is not set in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily check the certificate details:

- Open the Keychain Access app in Application/Utilities.
- Select My Certificates.
- Double Click the certificate.

You will be able to see the details of the certificate including the valid dates.

Comment: its valid till 4 july 2016, i am able to fix it by changing my date by 1 day add.
Current day+ 1 day add fix it. I don't know whats wrong with Indian Standard time with my mac mini keychain,otherwise its working fine in macbook air.

Comment: It is the "Not Valid Before" field that is the thing to check.

Comment: yes i have check it but it causes to either to wait 24 hour from now or to change my system time to validate it, do you know any reason to fix it? means so the keychain will take actual time and don't arise such error?